# Saving special characters in Enum data type

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to store and retrieve special characters (`/`, `*` etc) into/from DB table. This is my attempt:

```
public enum SpecialCharacters {
    Hack("H/K"), Gk("G*M");

    private String value;

    private SpecialCharacters(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.value; // This will return , # or +
    }
}

@Column(name = "Special_Char")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private SpecialCharacters specialCharacters;
...
```

But in DB table it stores only enum field Names like *Hack* and *Gk*, not **H/K** and **G*M**

Comment: Why do you think storing the enum names is wrong?

Comment: Cant you just use the value returned by `toString` from the retrieved enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `@Enumerated` Annotation you are only able to store the name or ordinal of your enum. With JPA 2.1 you can use the `@Converter` Annotation.

See Chapter 11.1.10 of the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf).

Example:

Enum:

```
public enum SpecialCharacter {
    Hack("H/K"),
    Gk("G*M");

    private String value;

    private SpecialCharacter(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.value; // This will return , # or +
    }

    public static SpecialCharacter valueOfKey(String key) {
        for (SpecialCharacter specialCharacter : values()) {
            if (specialCharacter.toString().equals(key)) {
                return specialCharacter;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal key");
    }
}
```

ConverterClass:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class SpecialCharacterConverter implements AttributeConverter<SpecialCharacter, String> {

    /**
     * Converts a {@link SpecialCharacter} to the correspondig String that is used in the database
     */
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(SpecialCharacter specialCharacter) {
        return specialCharacter.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Converts a String from the database to the corresponding {@link SpecialCharacter}.
     */
    @Override
    public SpecialCharacter convertToEntityAttribute(String dbValue) {
        return SpecialCharacter.valueOfKey(dbValue);
    }

}
```

Entity-Object:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {

    @Column(name = "Special_Char")
    private SpecialCharacter specialCharacter;

    public SpecialCharacter getSpecialCharacter() {
        return this.specialCharacter;
    }

    public void setSpecialCharacter(SpecialCharacter specialCharacter) {
        this.specialCharacter = specialCharacter;
    }
}
```

Comment: I Tried this But it Stores the Ordinal Value in My Data Base

Comment: Are you using a JPA 2.1 implementation? Don't forget "autoApply = true".

Comment: Yes I am Using JPA 2.1

Comment: I can confirm that the above solution works. We are using eclipselink. What happens if you annotate the field in your entity class with javax.persistence.Convert? -->@Convert(converter = SpecialCharacterConverter.class)

Comment: In DB it Stores only ordinal values instead of storing value .I have Checked all Possible ways using this code. Can any Suggestions?

Comment: Please check that you are using javax.persistence.Converter and not org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Converter. Or are you using Hibernate?